# Comments not displaying for node that was added to a custom page

Tags: comments

I’m attempting to make it possible for users to add comments to a custom page that was created via Page Manager. My understanding is that it is not possible to set up and allow commenting for page but only for nodes. Therefore i created a special content type and corresponding node and added it to the page. i added via ‘Add existing node’ option.

I’ve added comments to this special node but they are not being displayed when viewing the node in context of the custom page. Does anyone know how i can get these comments to display?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the default 'Basic page' content type to create page and allow comments there. If you need to have custom path for it, you can setup url alias. 
Also for additional customization or theming, you can opt for node specific template.

I hope my answer applies to your situation :)